# TrackballControls.js issues with MacBook Pro trackpad scroll function

Tags: three.js

Uncontrollable camera movement in a specific situation. I'm using the mouse scroll wheel to control zoom (pretty standard). Macbook trackpad scroll works with two finger contact and parallel, vertical movement. I haven't experimented with the zoom function when your fingers move apart. Use of the scroll function on the trackpad makes the scene zoom out "infinitely" no matter how far the user's fingers move.

Here's the breakdown:

- Using Three.js > TrackballControls.js
- Version of Three.js seems irrelevant.
- Browser seems to make a slight difference. Problem is exacerbated in Chrome, more stable in Firefox but still there.
- Sensitivity doesn't make too much difference. Both examples below use different ZoomSpeed constants.

Examples where the problem can be seen (Macbook required of course):

- [My current project](http://talbot.frisbeebiotech.com/atlas_webgl.html)
- [TrackballControls.js example page](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/misc_controls_trackball.html)

Thank you for your time!

**Added edit 23:00EDT 12/3/13 to specify question:**

Sorry I didn't specify. The scroll function of the MacBook trackpad may be accidentally or purposefully used to render the site useless for the user upon each visit. Refresh is the only way to reset the problem. What is the best way to approach this? Detect OS and disable scroll is an option but also a ridiculous one. This is an accessibility problem for any site that uses TrackballControls.js. How are other devs addressing this? Any ideas? That is my question. Thank you for your time!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify. The scroll function of the MacBook trackpad may be accidentally or purposefully used to render the site useless for the user upon each visit. Refresh is the only way to reset the problem. What is the best way to approach this? Detect OS and disable scroll is an option but also a ridiculous one. This is an accessibility problem for any site that uses TrackballControls.js. How are other devs addressing this? Any ideas? That is my question. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you saying that scrolling on the MacBook trackpad is too sensitive when using `TrackballControls`?

Comment: Yes, perhaps it is too sensitive. But how do you then differentiate between trackpad scroll and mouse wheel? Mouse wheel and other methods (such as key hold and mouse movement) work fine for zoom.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. Change the last line of code in the TrackballControl.js mousewheel event handler:

```
_zoomStart.y += ( 1 / delta ) * 0.05;
```

to this:

```
_zoomStart.y += delta * 0.01;
```

If your trackpad is anything like mine, it fires the mousewheel event more times but in smaller increments. Since the mousewheel delta was being inverted, the smaller increments were becoming larger increments, and since there were more of them, the zoom was being adjusted exponentially more. I'm not sure why it's inverted like that in the original code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I'll have to check it out when I have access to a MacBook again. Soon...

Thanks again!

Comment: It's now been fixed in the current version of TrackballControls.js: 
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js


You can test it here: 
http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/misc_controls_trackball.html